# Typescript constrain object creation to Record<string, T> but then get defined keys?

Tags: typescript

Let's say i have a type called Param which equals,

```js
type Param = {
 field: string;
 active: boolean;
}
```

I use this to create a record of any key (string) but with values that are of type Param e.g.,

```js
const params: Record<string, Param> = {
 foo: { field: 'hello', active: false },
 boo: { field: 'world', active: true },
} as const
```

Why can typescript not infer the keys of `params` are `'foo' | 'boo'`? Even when using `as const`.

Comment: because you have explicitly set it as `Record<string, Param>`.

Comment: Yes because at this point the keys are not defined but i wish to constrain the value to a particular type. Afterwards the keys are now well defined (along with the value being of type Param) so i wish to extract. It feels like it should be possible.

Comment: Just remove `Record<string, Param>`. You are forcing TS to make think, `params` is `Record<string, Param>`. So, when you are extracting keys from this type, you will not get real keys behind it.

Answer (score 7):

It is because you have explicitly set the type of `params` as `Record<string, Param>`. You will instead have to let it be dynamic and add some enforcement on the value type.

```
type Param = {
 field: string;
 active: boolean;
}

const params = {
 foo: { field: 'hello', active: false } as Param,
 boo: { field: 'world', active: true } as Param,
}

// "foo" | "bar"
type paramsKeys = keyof typeof params
```

If you are on typescript 4.9+, you can do this instead

```
const params = {
 foo: { field: 'hello', active: false },
 boo: { field: 'world', active: true },
} satisfies Record<string, Param>;

// "foo" | "bar"
type paramsKeys = keyof typeof params
```